# How to create new topic in c# by using kafka-net

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka

I have **HomeController** as below,

```
#region Properties

const string topic = "AnotherTestTopic";
const string host = "http://localhost:9092";

#endregion


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection form)
{
    var kafkaOptions = new KafkaOptions(new Uri(host));

    var brokerRouter = new BrokerRouter(kafkaOptions);

    var producer = new Producer(brokerRouter);

    producer.SendMessageAsync(topic, new[] { new Message("Test message") }).Wait();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

I am using kafka-net dll and my **SendMessageAsync** method as below

```
   public async Task<List<ProduceResponse>> SendMessageAsync(string topic, IEnumerable<Message> messages, Int16 acks = 1,
            TimeSpan? timeout = null, MessageCodec codec = MessageCodec.CodecNone)
        {
            if (_stopToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("Cannot send new documents as producer is disposing.");
            if (timeout == null) timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(DefaultAckTimeoutMS);

            var batch = messages.Select(message => new TopicMessage
            {
                Acks = acks,
                Codec = codec,
                Timeout = timeout.Value,
                Topic = topic,
                Message = message
            }).ToList();

            _asyncCollection.AddRange(batch);

            await Task.WhenAll(batch.Select(x => x.Tcs.Task));

            return batch.Select(topicMessage => topicMessage.Tcs.Task.Result)
                                .Distinct()
                                .ToList();
        }
```

**Question:**

I just started learning kafka.I really do not know how can i create topic from c# code.How can i add topic from c# ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `auto.create.topics.enable=true` in your broker configuration to let Kafka create the topic for you when it is not previously created.

You may also want to set `num.partitions` and `default.replication.factor` to appropriate values in your broker configuration as well.

Comment: where are the configuration files ?

Comment: it's in your broker's conf directory; usually called `server.properties`